# Put a fixation cross on top of a image in Expyriment?

Tags: experimental-psychology, software

I wanted to try to put a fixation cross on top of images presented to avoid subject eye movements as much as possible.

I am using Python's Expyriment package and thought that after `present` with a `expyriment.stimuli.Picture` I could do a `present` with an `expyriment.stimuli.FixCross` object using the `clear`or `update` input arguments. But this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
picture = expyriment.stimuli.Picture("/path/to/picture.jpg")
fixcross = expyriment.stimuli.FixCross()
picture.present(update=False)
fixcross.present(clear=False)
```

Alternatively, you can first plot the fixation cross on top of the picture and then present it:

```
picture = expyriment.stimuli.Picture("/path/to/picture.jpg")
fixcross = expyriment.stimuli.FixCross()
fixcross.plot(picture)
picture.present()
```